# Docker not starting - Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine

Tags: docker, installation

While trying to install docker and docker-compose with "curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | CHANNEL=stable sh" I was able to enable it, but as soon as I tried to start it shut down giving me the error "Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine".

I already tried to uninstall all of docker, purge the whole installation and reinstall it, also looked through several online questions that had the same issue but couldn't find any solution that worked for me yet.

journalctl -xe shows the following:

```
Apr 12 18:30:09 dockerd[29882]: time="2019-04-12T18:30:09.389632776+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Apr 12 18:30:09 kernel: llc: Unknown symbol pskb_trim_rcsum_slow (err 0)
Apr 12 18:30:09 kernel: llc: Unknown symbol pskb_trim_rcsum_slow (err 0)
Apr 12 18:30:09 dockerd[29882]: time="2019-04-12T18:30:09.433055198+02:00" level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'bridge': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)\nmodprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'br_netfilt
Apr 12 18:30:09 dockerd[29882]: time="2019-04-12T18:30:09.509866302+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Apr 12 18:30:09 kernel: llc: Unknown symbol pskb_trim_rcsum_slow (err 0)
Apr 12 18:30:09 kernel: llc: Unknown symbol pskb_trim_rcsum_slow (err 0)
Apr 12 18:30:09 dockerd[29882]: time="2019-04-12T18:30:09.558391253+02:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Apr 12 18:30:09 dockerd[29882]: Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: package not installed
Apr 12 18:30:09 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 12 18:30:09 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Would be very thankful if someone could help me with this issue (as I just want to install a mail service) or even just link me to an already answered/existing post where the same issue could be resolved.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot that. "Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"

Comment: Your default bridge networking failed. Are you running KVM/QEMU in parallel? I had a similar issue. I noticed that my default bridge was deactivated after reboot (test with: `sudo virsh net-list --all` and reactivate it with: `sudo virsh net-start default`) Both are KVM commands.